# Upgrading cakephp 2.x to 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to upgrade several of our cakephp 2 apps to cakephp 3 using the [upgrade tool](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/upgrade-tool.html) but I'm a little lost. On this [blog](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/upgrading-to-cakephp-3-0), in one of the comments it says that my application will need a copy of cakephp 3 for the upgrade. Do I install it in the root directory of my app or where exactly?

Should the commands be run like this

```
bin/cake upgrade all /root_directory/
```

or

```
bin/cake upgrade all /root_directory/app/
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is also a more complete [upgrade tool](https://github.com/dereuromark/upgrade). And yeah, those are separate apps. just put them somewhere on the same disk, and then use the full path to the actual app as path.

Comment: @mark Thanks Mark. Good stuff.